# printf of longs

Tags: c, printf, long-integer

I implemented myPrintf function:

```
int myPrintf(const char* format,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int ret = vprintf (format, args);
    fflush(stdout);
    va_end (args);
    return ret;
}
```

When I run the function with format = "%ld,%ld"
and the `args` representation as set of chars is `78,97,188,0,0,0,0,0,120,10,227,5,0,0,0,0`
the output printed to stdout is `12345678,0`.Instead of `12345678,98765432`.
What could be the problem?And how could it be solved?

Comment: Show your code. The `args` cannot be a set of chars (which has no sense). you should pass a variadic argument list. You can call `myprintf("%ld,%ld", 2L, 3L);`

Comment: Please show the code where you call myPrintf. Note that %ld expects you to pass long's, not chars.

Comment: It is impossible  to show how I call it - it is difficult procedure .....I just showed the stack(memory) layout for the call

Comment: Huh?  Why would it be impossible to show how you call it?  It's just a C function call, right?  If the first argument to `myPrintf` is `"%ld,%ld"`, the second and third arguments need to be of type `long`.  If they aren't, then that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, like on ideone, your `long`s are 32 bits
http://ideone.com/jjafU

If you use `"%lld"` for 64-bit values, it works as you expect
http://ideone.com/BYTaa

Comment: just to be clear: `"%ld"` is the correct printf-format for `long int` whatever its size.

Comment: Thanks @JF, as Yakov's using C99, he'd be better of using the macros in `<inttypes.h>` anyway. `myPrintf("%" PRId64 " %" PRId64 "\n", data);`